# How to include jQuery in this chrome extension file?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to write a chrome extension, and would like to include jQuery in a file I am using. I have read many answers on here but I still don't get it. I might be going about it the wrong way, so please let me know. In my browser popup, popup.html, I have the user clicking a button, which then calls my content.js file, which is just a simple alert for now, but eventually I intend on using it to manipulate the DOM on the page the extension is used on. I would like to attach a locally saved copy of the jQuery library so I can write my DOM manipulation code with jQuery. I have tried adding it as my background file and also in my content_script section similarly but it still does not appear to load. Here is my code

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
            "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "wfhm.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "icons": {
        "128": "wfhm128.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery.js"]
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="width: 300px"> 
    <h2>test</h2>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Search by name..'/>
    <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function search() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'content.js'
  }); 
}

document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', search);
```

and content.js

```
$(function(){
    alert('hi');
    $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background scripts are in a separate environment from popup scripts (and from content scripts).  This means that the jQuery that you have loaded isn’t being seen.  Instead, you need to use popup.js to execute jQuery, and then use the callback to execute your content script:

popup.js:

```
function search() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'jquery.js'},function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'});
  });
}

document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', search);
```

And since the tab will have already loaded, you don’t need to worry about the `$(function())` in your content script.  You can just run your script.

Comment: Thank you a million times over. I've been struggling for hours on this